# Gef: How to access GraphicalEditor instance from EditPart?

Tags: java, eclipse-gef

Inside an EditPart class, I need the instance of the GraphicalEditor this EditPart belongs to. What is the easiest way to do this without passing the required object to the EditPartFactories and on to the EditParts?

Comment: Tried to find something... no way that I know of :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem: I can just access the EditPart via

```
Workbench.getInstance().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActiveEditor();
```

This works because I can assume that the EditPart has focus when this code is executed, which I forgot to mention in my question.